# Why does ICQ bot not send message?

Tags: perl, bots, icq

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::OSCAR qw(:standard);
$uin="7777777"; 
$password="1234567";
$sender = "43214312";
$text = "test";
$oscar = Net::OSCAR -> new();
$oscar -> signon($uin, $password);
$oscar -> send_im($sender, $text);
$oscar -> signoff();
```

why dont send me message?

Answer (score 7):

You don't do any [error checking](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aOSCAR#ERROR_HANDLING). Do that and the problem will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the ORIGINAL author of this software, wow - surprised it's still in use.. I've not touched it in years..

In short, the software uses Net::Oscar which is a library I took over as maintainer of years ago, but after a lawsuit with AOL ( over icqbot, not oscar ) .. I lost my desire to work on either.. I know that the net::oscar library was still downloaded and used for years after but I've not personally maintained it and I don't know if anyone has forked off of my work.. the icqbot software itself runs atop that library, so as long as it's methods work.. it will work.. but I've not updated icqbot in YEARS ..

Frankly I'm honored to have found this =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm amazed that me, as the author.. got nothing and someone else got 7 .. amusing :) but seriously the library is extremely outdated and the protocol has changed.. I no longer maintain the software.. I have no interest in returning to it...

Ps. The other guy is right though, no error checking is a bad idea.. that's how hacks happen.. it's just sloppy code... no offence, good luck... there's other ways to accomplish what you wanted now days.. :) for me it was a means to an end for an AI chat bot.

- Lonnie Waugh